# NO such file or directory for the files -----stdarg.h and float.h?

Tags: ios, c, llvm-gcc

I am using some files on .mm extension in the xcode project for compiling these files we have added the LLVM-GCC 4.2 in the build setting after adding this compiler this showing the error

> `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory`
>
> `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.sdk/usr/include/float.h:8:24: error: float.h: No such file or directory`

i have no idea how to remove this error any help to remove this error.

thanks

Balraj

Comment: If you accept some answers you are more likely to get people to bother answering

Answer (score 1):

These headers aren't supported in gcc 4.2 which is used by default on Mac OSX.

Switch to version 4.0 (it is described [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/20268-stdarg-h-float-h-build-errors.html))

Comment: actually i am using xcode sdk 3.1 to use that code and also setting the whole project build by LLMV GCC 4.2 and after  i adding it shows only two these directory file error else i do it with the gcc 4.0 as it stated in your link it throws the many errors so is there any way to add these files in that compiler directory 

please guide me !!!

Comment: * Are you sure that those were errors and not warnings? If latter, you can probably ignore them.
* If they are errors, consider commenting out #include's you have problems with. It is possible that they won't be really needed for your project. 
* Otherwise, you can look at this post http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/xcode-users@lists.apple.com/msg17102.html

Author says that reason is in missing headers in /usr/lib/gcc/4.2/include (or somewhere near it). You may try to copy missing files from prior version of gcc (4.0, e.g.).

Unfortunately, I can't check whether any of these works =(

Comment: pls check these are the error

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.sdk/usr/include/float.h:8:24: error: float.h: No such file or directory

these are the errors that are coming on !!!

Comment: as far as I remember, there're 'include_next' clauses in files stdarg.h and float.h in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.sdk/usr/include/

this means that preprocessor tries to find additional includes with the same name in other folder and when it can't it shows you errors you've decribed. Pretty messy if you ask me.

This is decribed here http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/xcode-users@lists.apple.com/msg17102.html.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and couldn't fix the problem with all other answers here,
so I tried:

```
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/include
sudo mv stdarg.h stdarg.h.original
sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.0.1/include/stdarg.h
```

and the compile error is gone!

Comment: Worked! Although, slightly different paths for me because I installed Xcode in a custom location (not default). Just look at the path in the errors. Use the same paths relative to this answer. If running on simulator,`iPhoneOS` will be `iPhoneSimulator`, and of course, `3.2.sdk` may vary, depending on which SDK you're building for.

Comment: Shorten the last line to `sudo ln -s ../lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.0.1/include/stdarg.h`. Also, should I use `arm-apple-darwin9` or `10`? I'm gonna go with `10`.

Comment: Interesting. However (and please excuse me if I'm stating the obvious), this seems like a test and not a practical solution, correct? This kind of thing could be extremely painful for larger teams or open source projects— hacking system-level files really never seems to be a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

I had this already on the GCC 4.0 compiler Changing to the LLVM compiler 1.6 worked for me.  Using Mac OS X 10.7.3 Xcode 3.2.5

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well, and changing to GCC 4.0 didn't fix it for me. I also had to change my active SDK (drop-down in the upper-left corner of the Xcode editor or console window) from 10.4 (Base SDK) to 10.6 (I'm running Snow Leopard).

I don't know what implications this might have on your development, but it was good enough for my problem because I'm just doing a basic command-line tool for easy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error building my Hello World app in xcode after doing an install of the SDL framework.  Doing the standard install, by the book, into Snow Leopard OSX 10.6.3 with xcode 3.3.2 threw those errors,

"stdarg.h: No such file or directory"
"float.h: No such file or directory"

because it defaults to SDK 10.4.

If you have that issue set the SDK to 10.6 and you should be in the clear.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing and based on what's been suggested above, the issue goes hand-in-hand with the Base SDK version; that is, earlier SDKs will only work with GCC 4.0, while later SDKs work with GCC 4.0 or 4.2 (and the newer LLVM options).

To summarize options that *should* work:

**Base SDK for iOS projects/targets:**
*iOS 3.2 and earlier:* GCC 4.0
*iOS 4.0 and later:* GCC 4.0, GCC 4.2, LLVM GCC 4.2, LLVM Clang

**Base SDK for Mac OS X projects/targets:**
*Mac OS X 10.5 and earlier:* GCC 4.0
*Mac OS X 10.6 and later:* GCC 4.0, GCC 4.2, LLVM GCC 4.2, LLVM Clang

Answer (score 0):

add additional flags like below

```
CFLAGS += -I"$(YOUR_SYSROOT)/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include"
CPPFLAGS += -I"$(YOUR_SYSROOT)/usr/include/c++/4.2.1"
CPPFLAGS += -I"$(YOUR_SYSROOT)/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/armv6-apple-darwin10"
```