# Deploy Django app on heroku. Who has suceeded?

Tags: django, heroku

When I launch command line:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The following error shows:

```
command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If not already done, installing gcc >= 4.0 on your system might help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install the requirements manually? That automatically happens when you deploy to Heroku, as long as you have a `requirements.txt` file in the root of the repo.

Comment: of course but when I launch command: pip install -r requirements.txt install django and psycopg2 but at end of file the error that comes up is: unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory. I go on however?

Comment: @magino85: Are you installing locally (i.e., on your own development machine)? If so, then you'll have to install gcc.

Comment: Yes locally...But how do you install?

Comment: @magino85: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. The issue was that pip was looking for gcc in the /Developer folder, which does not exist on my system. I ended up creating the folder that pip was looking for (/Developer/usr/bin) and adding a symbolic link to /usr/bin/gcc in this new folder. The command to do this is `ln -s /usr/bin/gcc gcc`. In your case, you can replace `gcc` with `gcc-4.0`. I hope this helps.

You can find some more information here: [gcc-4.2 error when using pip in virtualenv on OSX 10.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7949024/1243834).