# Python import MySQLdb error

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm having trouble importing MySQLdb to python.
I'm using python 2.7 in Mavericks.

I followed [this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949024/gcc-4-2-error-when-using-pip-in-virtualenv-on-osx-10-7) (and links therein) to install, and it all looked good up until the end. But I am getting the following error when I import the module in Python.

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you compile it yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061277/python-mysql-wrong-architecture-error