# How to install psycopg2 for django on mac

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I have postgresql installed (with postgresql app). When I try "pip install psycopg2", i get "unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory. How to fix?

Comment: gcc-4.2 is not installed. Does this solve your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8424885/4291583

Comment: if you mean : "sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2"; then nope

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

`pip install psycopg2`

try

`pip install psycopg2-binary`

Answer (score 0):

You will need XCode to compile with gcc on macOS.
Install it with this command in the terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Or you cold install it from the app store.

Comment: It is already installed, forgot to mention that im trying to install within a virtual environment

Comment: What does `gcc --version`output?

Comment: Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: Is the path to Postgres.app binaries available in the virtual environment? Set it with: `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

Comment: Yes. Did it to fix my pg_config problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) and Python Setup Tools/PIP to install all you packages for django.
This makes your job of package installs/upgrades very easy.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

This will install the virtualenv. Now create and activate a virtual environment using this virtualenv like this:

```
virtualenv <any_name_you_want_for_this_virtual_env>
e.g.
virtualenv api-venv
```

This will create a directory: api-venv in the current directory you are in.
Now activate this environment and then install all your packages using 'pip' command. This way, pip will install all packages inside this api-venv environment only.

```
source api-venv/bin/activate
```

Now the api-venv is activated. Let's install 'psycopg2'

```
pip install psycopg2
```

I would recommend to install django inside this venv so everything is in the venv.

```
pip install django
```

You can create as many such virtual environments as you like with different configuration.
Done!

Comment: decent advice but you aren't really addressing OP's issue with needing to compile `psychopg2`.  The `pip install` isn't going to help there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. First, you should install PostgreSQL through brew.

```
    brew install postgresql
```

Then you should add pg_config to PATH. You can find pg_config with.

```
    which pg_config
```

Finally, install psycopg2 with pip.

```
    pip install psycopg2
```